# Dart : The getter was called on null. Immediately after null check

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I have a piece of code that looks like this :

```dart
    if (mapController != null) {
      final LatLng oldLatLng = mapController.center;   // this is line 185 in stMapScreen.dart
```

I am sometimes (via [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) error catching) getting the following error :

```
NoSuchMethodError: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'center' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: center
  File "map.dart", line 44, in MapControllerImpl.center
  File "stMapScreen.dart", line 185, in _StMapScreenState.glideToLocation
```

**I'm struggling to understand how I can get a "*called on null*" error in the line after a `!= null` check.**

I don't know how to consistently reproduce the error.
**I'm just asking for answers on how it's possible theoretically.**

The `mapController` var is a MapController class from the [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) library.

Comment: Is this the only place its called? Maybe its called somewhere else?

Comment: Can you add some code to print the mapController before null check? Knowing your mapController string maybe show your problem.

Comment: Plase share more code. The entire method will be good.

Comment: I think the mapController is not null but the value inside the mapController.center has a null value. Can you please print the value of mapController.center?

Comment: Thank you @ToraCode, @YoBo, and @Gourango - I'll add something in to catch the value of `mapController` for the next time this happens and will update this question anon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always pay close attention to the details from the stack trace.  In your case, it says:

```dart
NoSuchMethodError: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'center' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: center
  File "map.dart", line 44, in MapControllerImpl.center
```

The null pointer exception came from `MapControllerImpl`.  Glancing at the code to `package:flutter_map`, `MapControllerImpl` comes from the package, not your code.  [The referenced line](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/blob/85558c9194f0f0b7b1f7b20e6d487d8fdfe523fb/lib/src/map/map.dart#L44) seems to be:

```dart
  LatLng get center => _state.center;
```

So `MapControllerImpl`'s internal `_state` variable is null.  I am not familiar with `package:flutter_map`, but possibly you should check `mapController.ready` first (or otherwise ensure that its `state` is set).